# Respond to selected email and choose from available signatures

Tags: vba, outlook

I send a standard response, to selected email, with specified signature.

I hard code my signature name but would like to dynamically select the signature.

I have:

```vb
Sub Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Html_2()
    Dim SigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olReply As MailItem ' Reply
    Dim olRecip As Recipient ' Add Recipient

    'Change Response1.htm to the name of your signature
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\1.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
   
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll
        Set olRecip = olReply.Recipients.Add(" ") ' Recipient Address
        olRecip.Type = olCC
        olReply.HTMLBody = Signature & olReply.HTMLBody
        olReply.Display

        'olReply.Send
    Next olItem
End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String<br>
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

I have 10 suppliers to follow up with.
Instead of doing reply all to each one of them and selecting the signature, I would like to respond to all of them with the signature in one go.
Currently, the code only works on the signature named '1.htm' which I can change manually but I want to select which signature to use for responding. In this way, the procedure becomes more generic.

Is there a way that I can select the .htm file (similar to file explorer in Excel VBA) and feed that name to SigString?

Comment: You could remove the signature from the code and choose it manually. You could write matching code for each signature.

Comment: That will only pull things backward. I want the code to be more useful to the general pool.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate the default signature?

Comment: My scenario is that I have 10 supplier's who I want to follow up with. So, instead of doing reply all to each one of them and selecting the signature, I would like to respond to all of them with the signature in one go. Currently, the code only works on the signature named '1.htm' which I can change manually but I want the ability to select which signature to use for responding. In this way, the procedure becomes more generic to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogs may be opened through Excel VBA.

```vb
Sub chooseFile()
    
    Dim sigPath As String
    Dim sigString As String
    
    sigPath = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    sigString = browseForFile(sigPath)
    
    Debug.Print sigString
    
End Sub

Function browseForFile(startFolder As String) As String

    Dim xlApp As Object
    
    ' Set reference to Microdoft Office XX.X Object Library
    Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set fDialog = xlApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select one file"
        .InitialFileName = startFolder
        
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "all files", "*.htm"
    
        If .Show = True Then
            browseForFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "Cancel."
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_BasedOnAddress()

Dim sigString As String
Dim Signature As String

Dim olItem As Object
Dim olReply As MailItem     ' Reply
Dim olRecip As Recipient    ' Add Recipient

If ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then

    sigString = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    
    For Each olItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
    
        If olItem.Class = olMail Then
        
            Set olReply = olItem.replyall
                        
            If olItem.SenderEmailAddress = "Address1@somewhere.com" Then
                sigString = sigString & "1.htm"
    
            ElseIf olItem.SenderEmailAddress = "Address2@somewhere.com" Then
                sigString = sigString & "2.htm"
                
            ' ...
            
            Else
                sigString = sigString & "standardReply.htm"
                
            End If
            
            Signature = GetBoiler_IfFileExists(sigString)
            
            olReply.HTMLBody = Signature & olReply.HTMLBody
            olReply.Display
            'olReply.Send
            
        End If
        
    Next olItem
    
End If

End Sub


Function GetBoiler_IfFileExists(ByVal sFile As String) As String

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object

If dir(sFile) <> "" Then
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler_IfFileExists = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    
Else
    GetBoiler_IfFileExists = ""
    
End If

End Function
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Is there a way that I can select the .htm file (similar to file explorer in excel VBA) and feed that name to SigString variables filename?